# Why is there a FileNotFoundError for one code but not others?

Tags: python, filenotfounderror

I used these same exact lines in two different python files:

```
inFile = open('wordlist.txt','r+')
words = inFile.readlines()
```

In one of them everything runs fine, but in the other it gives me a FileNotFoundError.  I'm not sure if anyone wants to see both of the complete files, but is there anything I can do to solve the problem just right off the top of your head? Any tips are appreciated. Thank you!

edit: Since I couldn't resolve this problem, I have decided to try using these lines instead:

```
import random
from words import words
import string
```

For context, I am writing code for a hangman game.  I have a python file just with a list of words named words, and it's in the same folder as my hangman file. However, I still get an error telling me that the module words does not exist.

Comment: The file one is looking for is there, and the file the other one is looking for is missing?

Comment: 'wordlist.txt' is not at the same root level as the python file you running.  Make sure you specify the full path to your 'wordlist.txt' if it is not in the same root level.

Comment: Use of relative pathnames is fraught with danger. Don't do it

Comment: Probably your two python files are not located in the same directory. You call 'wordlist.txt' as relative path. You might try the absolute path (i.e.: "D:/path/to/file/windows")

Comment: Sorry, could you please explain the concept of "relative path"?

Comment: The two python files are both looking for the same wordlist.txt file, and in one it works, but in the other it doesn't.

Comment: As others have mentioned: *are both Python files in the same folder?*

Comment: A relative path is one that doesn't start at the root of a filesystem.  Since your filename doesn't contain a path at all, it's relative.

Comment: Ah, I see.  Yes, they are in the same folder.  I think I solved the problem.  Thanks for everyone's replies.

Comment: What was the solution? You can post an answer yourself.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that for whatever reason, there were multiple copies of the same hangman python file.  One of them was in the same folder as the wordlist.txt file, but the one that I was running was not.  The solution was just to delete the extra copies and keep the one copy that was in the same folder as wordlist.txt.